# NoReverseMatch at /api/users/request-reset-email/

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

This is not duplicate issue, I have already referred old question, but no answer was found. I am using Django==1.10.5

I am trying to implement rest password functionality using Django rest framework. But I am getting below error..

```
    Reverse for 'api/password_reset_confirm2' with arguments '('uidb64', 'token')' 
and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

If you look the patters searched error shows, it was unable read any url patters that are configured in URL.py. That is the worry.

**Reset Password Class:**

```
class RequestPasswordResetEmailAPIView(GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = ResetPasswordEmailSerializer

    def post(self,request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        email = request.data.get('email','')
        if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            user = User.objects.get(email=email)
            uidb64 = urlsafe_base64_encode(smart_bytes(user.id))
            token = PasswordResetTokenGenerator().make_token(user)
            current_site = get_current_site(
                request=request
            ).domain
            relativeLink = reverse('api/password_reset_confirm2'
                                   ,args={'uidb64':uidb64, 'token': token}
                                   )
            absurl = 'http://'+current_site+relativeLink
            email_body = 'Hello'+absurl
            data = {'email_body': email_body, 'to_email': user.email, 'email_subject': 'Reset password link' }
            Util.send_email(data)
        return Response('Success')
```

My url.py for authentication app looks like this

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^user/?$', UserRetrieveUpdateAPIView.as_view()),
    url(r'^users/?$', RegistrationAPIView.as_view()),
    url(r'^users/login/?$', LoginAPIView.as_view()),
    url(r'^users/request-reset-email/',RequestPasswordResetEmailAPIView.as_view(), name='users/request-reset-email'),
    url(r'^users/password-reset-confirm/(?P<uidb64>[-\w]+)/(?P<token>[-\w]+)/$', PasswordResetTokenCheckAPIView.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm2'),
    # path('password-reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', RequestPasswordResetEmailAPIView.as_view(), name='api/password_reset_confirm2'),


]
```

And in Main url.py, urls are connfigured like this

```
 url(r'^api/', include('apps.authentication.urls', namespace='authentication')),
```

Please advice,
Thank you

Comment: I think I see a typo `relativeLink = reverse('api/password_reset_confirm2', ...)`.
Your Url doesn't have the `2` after the `password_reset_confirm`. 

Maybe this is the issue?

Comment: By removing and adding 2 I have tried, I had doubt that it may conflict with in built url names, so added 2 at the end. But still does not works

Comment: Oh ok. I was saying this because plenty of StackOverflow problems are caused by a simple typo.

Comment: I guess your path is commented `# path('password-reset/<uidb64>/<token>/'` try to remove `#`

Comment: I am not using paht, instead I am using urlpatters

Comment: as per error  keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: [], Reverse url unable to read any url patters why?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
relativeLink = reverse(
    'authentication:api/password_reset_confirm2',
    args={'uidb64':uidb64, 'token': token}
)
```

Comment: Some people will just fall from heaven to save... Thank you..it resolved my problem, but I did not understand what I was doing wrong, how your solution works :)

Comment: As far as your are using `unclude` you need to show the hierarchy of includes. Here is the official docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/#reversing-namespaced-urls

Answer (score 0):

Your URL reference in the `reverse` function may be conflicting with your `urls` in another app.
Instead of:

```
relativeLink = reverse('api/password_reset_confirm2'
                       ,args={'uidb64':uidb64, 'token': token}
                      )
```

Try this:

```
relativeLink = reverse('password_reset_confirm2'
                                   ,args={'uidb64':uidb64, 'token': token}
                                   )
```

Now you are referencing the URL by its name.

Comment: Same error appeared, Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm2' with arguments '('uidb64', 'token')' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []